# How to escape database path

Tags: javascript, escaping, xpages

I have a field in a notesdocument containing a path to a database using backslases (i.e Folder1\Folder2\start.nsf)

and I am trying to redirect users when clicking a div with the following client side code

```
location.href= "#{javascript:dbdoc.getItemValueString('DatabasePath')}"
```

but the back slases are not returned , all I get is a string with all the folders without slashes so the url do not work

how can I escape the path correctly so that the link works?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Have you tried to simply replace the backslashes with slashes? Like `location.href= "#{javascript: return "/"+dbdoc.getItemValueString('DatabasePath').replace(/\\/g,"/");}"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JavaScript's [escape](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_escape.asp) function:

```
location.href= "#{javascript:escape(dbdoc.getItemValueString('DatabasePath'))}"
```

Comment: ofcourse, thought I tried that!!, works like a charm